# Windows SBS 2008 and DNS issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns, windows-sbs

We have a windows 2008 SBS, roughly every couple of days no machine on the network can access sites such as google/msn/bbc etc. Its solved easily by rebooting the DNS on the server, however this obviously should noy happen, can anyone suggest a reason or offer debugging assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had that exact same problem.  The workaround was to add DNS forwarders into DNS on the SBS rather than just using root hints.

While this isn't best practice, we haven't found a better resolution yet.

Is the box fully up to date?

Comment: @northirid Yea all updates and patches are on. Can you decribe exactly what you did? This isnt our area of expertise :(

Comment: Sure. Open up the DNS console on the SBS.
Right click on [servername] and choose properties.
Open the Forwarders tab and then click Edit.
To add (for example) Google DNS, type 8.8.8.8 then press enter, then type 8.8.4.4 and press enter.
Click OK, then OK again.
For completeness sake, rightclick on [servername] again and go to All Tasks, then click Restart.

Let me know how you go!

Comment: Thanks, will try now. Why is this not best practice and what are the negitives?

Comment: To be bluntly honest, I'm not sure.  I think it has to do with the fact that DNS providers (eg your ISP) are "unreliable" in the real world.  I have never actually had an issue with using forwarders. This had a bit of info on it. (SBS Diva link) http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2008/12/14/dns-root-hints-and-forwarders.aspx